# Getting list of unique objects from list of duplicates in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following List of Map Objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
    "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
    "type": "CASHIER"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam Perera",
    "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-3eee-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
    "type": "CASHIER"
  },
  {
    "name": "Uma Jackson",
    "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-5634-f3d0caba2bb3",
    "type": "CASHIER"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anu Ima",
    "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-lksa-f3d0caba2bb3",
    "type": "CASHIER"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
    "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
    "type": "CASHIER"
  }
];
```

I want to remove the duplicate items from this List. How can I do that in Flutter?

P.S. - `.toSet()` and `.toList()` methods did not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you store the entire list in a List l1=[. . .], use toSet() for removing duplicates:

```
l1.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: This only works if the elements of the list are considered equal though

Comment: @Ivo yes. This does not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's sufficient to only check on equal `userID`s you could do this:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main(){
  final list = [
    {
      "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sam Perera",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-3eee-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Uma Jackson",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-5634-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Anu Ima",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-lksa-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    }
  ];

  final result = groupBy(list, (Map e) => e['userID']).values.map((e) => e.first).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method which will filter items by specific field occurrence in `Set`:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filterListByKey (
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list,
  String key
) {
  Set ids = Set<String>();
  
  return list.where((e) {
    if (ids.contains(e[key].toString())) {
      return false;
    }
    
    ids.add(e[key].toString());
    return true;
  }).toList();
}
```

and use it:

```dart
void main() {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
    {
      "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sam Perera",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-3eee-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Uma Jackson",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-5634-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Anu Ima",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-f6f4-4ddd-lksa-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sameera Tennakoon",
      "userID": "7c770f8d-hju4-4ddd-b5cb-f3d0caba2bb3",
      "type": "CASHIER"
    }
  ];
  final uniqueUsers = filterListByKey(users, 'userID');
  
  print(uniqueUsers);
  
}
```

You can [test it here](https://replit.com/@num8er/UniqueListFromListOfMaps?v=1#main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove duplicates from a List of Map objects in Flutter without using a set is by iterating over the List and adding each Map object to a new List only if it does not already exist in the new List.

```dart
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> originalList = [...];
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> newList = [];

originalList.forEach((map) {
  if (!newList.any((newMap) => newMap['userID'] == map['userID'])) {
    newList.add(map);
  }
});

print(newList);
```